# Should i avoid JOIN when MySQL not optimizing them?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, optimization

In university SQL course relation database was all about JOINS between tables.
So i adopted general approach to first do all necessary JOINS, then select data, filter with WHERE, GROUP BY when neccesary. This way code and logic is straightforward.

But very often when things get more complicated than a single LEFT JOIN, i get very poor performance.

Today i just rewrote JOIN query, which 600 second execution time
to different approach with:
*SELECT (SELECT ... WHERE ID = X.ID) FROM X*
and
*SELECT ... WHERE Y IN (SELECT ...)*
and now it finishes in 0.0027 seconds.

I am frustrated, i use indexes on fields on which i join, but performance is so poor...

Comment: What a rhetorical question. Joins are slow, avoid them if possible. You cannot avoid joins in all cases, joins are necessary for some tasks. If you want help with some query optimizing, please provide more details. Everything matters: query, data, indexes, plan, etc.

Comment: Yes, i understand that my question is not too specific... But i am sure people with experience can give me good advice on the matter. Actually, statement "Joins are slow, avoid them if possible" from experienced person is quite useful.

Comment: While rewrite without `JOIN` still giving the best results,, by using `EXPLAIN _query_` i also found out that my indexing was incomplete. I mistakenly ommited indexing for joins to certain table, because there was like only 40 records, my bad... After that, old query finished like in 1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` *may*, but does not always, force looking at the 'left' table first.

`JOINs` (but not `LEFT JOINs`) plus a `WHERE` that touches *one* table gives the Optimizer a strong, reliable, hint to look at that one table first.

`JOIN`, plus a `WHERE` touching multiple table -- the Optimizer sometimes picks the right 'first' table, sometimes does not.

The Optimizer *usually* gets the rows from one table (whichever it picked as the best to start with), then does a NLJ (Nested Loop Join).  This means reaching into the next table one row at a time.  This 'reach' needs a good index.

`IN ( SELECT ... )`, in *old* versions was *terribly* unoptimal.  Now, it may turn into a "semi-join", like an `EXIST ( SELECT ... )` and be quite efficient.  Sometimes manually doing such is beneficial.

"Explode-Implode" hits a lot of people.  This is where there is a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY`.  The grouping is mostly to implode the large number of rows created by the join.  Sometimes a "derived" table can be an excellent optimization.  (This is a manual reformulation of the query.)

Often a `LEFT JOIN` that is used for an aggregate can be folded in something like this: `SELECT ..., ( SELECT SUM(foo) FROM ... ) AS foos, ...`, thereby mitigating the explode-implode.

Not understanding the benefit of 'composite' indexes is perhaps the most common problem on this forum.

Shall I ramble on?  I doubt if I have covered more than 1/4 of the cases.  So, I agree with @leftjoin.

Here are some simple tips:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Ok, so that "Explode-Implode" is known thing... i though Optimizer will automatically group by right table first... good to know it does not.

Comment: (I made up "Explode-Implode" as the term for that common Optimization problem.)